# Qlikview Load subquery like SQL

Tags: load, qlikview

Want to know if I can write load query to do below logic:

Logic in SQL as example:

```
 SELECT A,B,C, COUNT(B) AS E, SUM(D)  
  FROM (
        SELECT A,B,C, COUNT(B) AS D
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE A IN ('a','b','c')
        GROUP BY A,B,C
  ) a
  WHERE A = 'a'
  GROUP BY A,B,C
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
LOAD
A, B, C, count(B) as E, sum(D)
where A = 'a'
group by A, B, C
;
LOAD
    A, 
    B, 
    C,
    count(B) as D
where match(A, 'a', 'b', 'c') > 0
group by A, B, C
;
load * inline [
    A, B, C, D
    a, b, c, 50
    b, h, t, 99
    c, b, c, 99
    d, b, c, 99
    testA, testB, testC, 100
];
```